# Where to manage entity state change in multi tier application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, mvvm, architecture

I build a multi tier application in .Net/C#/EF6/WPF/WCF.

The backend is a mysql database with an entity framework layer to access the database. I have a business logic layer and a facade layer to expose the service.

On the client side, a WPF/MVVM client.

I have 3 models, one for the client ("view domain"), one for the backend generated by entity framework ("db domain") and a dto-like one for the services.

On the client side I track entity state changes, I basically copy the `EntityState` enum from `System.Data` and set the state whenever a property is changed or when a new entity is created.

For instance, one of my services expose `Add(Entity e)` and `Update(Entity e)`.

Should I take the decision to call one method or another on the client (he knows if the state is `Added` or `Modified`) or should I expose a single method called `AddOrUpdate(Entity e)` and let the backend decide if it's a new or update entity ?

What's the best approach for that ? Should I take decision client-side or backend-side regarding that ?

Comment: if you have multi layer application and have a data access layer you should be validate and control state of rows in data access layer , but in entityframwork you don't need control state of entity (like data set state) and you can call save changes to commit all of changes, but if you need to control the state you can control it in facade and then decide what method of data access or rule layer most be call

Comment: For me, a more important question is whether a client should do change tracking at all. Technically, the client always has stale data, so each data point is potentially "modified" even if the client doesn't know that. Only the server is geared to comparing current state. Also, the service can't trust each client to do it right, so always it has to check/validate changes anyway.

Comment: You have two way to control state nicly 1. You can control the state in facade and then if you need call the rule layer and rule call the dataaccess layer and if you need return an error to presentation layer you do not need to go to rule or dataaccess layer ... 2. another way you can use a http module to check this kind of situation . in this case you do not have fake service call ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want the client to know/handle the state of an object.
Your problem is probably caused because you reuse the "Entity" class in both methods.

I think you can use something like this:

```
 Add(InputResource e) 
 Update(UpdateResource e)
```

None of the above should have a "State" property*.
The "InputResource" shouldn't have an Id/Primary Key either

I think the above approach is cleaner but it depends on your needs.
If you want to go with the "AddOrUpdate" I still don't think adding a State is a good idea.
You can check the Id property,if it is set it's an Update ,if not it is an Add

*Of course I'm talking about your public API.
Internally,on your server (BusinessLayer-DataLayer) you might have a solution that handles items based on their state but I don't think you are taking about this